# Querying in linked server problem - Remote access is not supported for transaction isolation level "SNAPSHSHOT"

Tags: c#, sql-server, axapta, linked-server

My problem is that I'm joining table from the current SQL Server and Linked Server database table in my query.

I tried to query it inside MS SQL Server and it was okay no problems with it. But when I tried it with C# it produced an error. I'm afraid to try other solutions since it is a crucial time for me to mess up.

The Linked Server database is a standard database in Microsoft Dynamics AX, and I guess I should not alter it just to make my task work.

I just want to double check this with all of you guys, I'm seeking for your suggestions. Do you think that SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON is the best solution?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU721.jpg

My expected result is just to execute my query with no error.

Comment: Your image link doesn't work - please copy paste whatever you're seeing

Comment: It occured in DbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReder()
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occured in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Remote access is not supported for transaction isolation level "SNAPSHOT"

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @Ken White I provided image, and it is working.

Comment: Images are not code. Code is typed in a text or code editor, and can be copied and pasted directly into your question. You didn't write your SQL in an image editor.  See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons that images of code are not acceptable. You can also see the [tour] and read the [help] pages, especially [ask] and the [mcve] link I provided before.

Comment: Do NOT change the AX database via SQL. During a DB sync, your changes would get removed automatically and/or cause the sync to fail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are enlisted on a distributed transaction. The error is telling you that what you are trying to do is not supported by SQL server, therefore, the alternative that I would recommend is to change your transaction isolation level to something different, like `READ COMMITTED`.

If you are using `System.Trasactions` for transaction control, try something like this:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
};

using (var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
    // Database access logic goes here...
}
```

Or if you are using the `SqlTransaction` class:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection())
{
    cn.Open();
    using (var tran = cn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        // Database access logic...
    }
}
```

You can find more details in the official SQL server documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks

There you can see that "snapshot isolation" is not supported on distributed transactions.